# Cannot see build phases, general settings in Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, project-settings

I just downloaded the XCode 6.1 seed.

I am have this issue with one specific project. 
The project information view is absolutely different.
The General, Build phases sections are all missing. 
All I can see is info and build setting.

Anyone else faced this issue?
None of my other old projects has this issue.

Answer (score 5):

It's a sneaky one - you click the show/`hide Project Targets List` icon and it pops out the Project name and its targets underneath.
Click one of those and you'll get the *Build Phases* option showing up. [image]

Answer (score 1):

OP's problem was that the **Build Phases** did not show up when opening the project settings.

### Simple Fix:

[image]

Expand the left side bar.

Your **project** file is selected. (in my case it's called "opengl-series")
This is the problem.

[image]

You want to select the **App**. (in my case "CGTutorial")

**Build phases** now shows, along with the other settings.

Comment: feel free to accept an answer that works for you. @Neil